# I need to call a function when previous function has finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJs and I use this function in my controller to get data from database

```
this.callServer = function callServer(criteria) {
    ctrl.searchParameters = criteria;
    ctrl.isLoading = true;
    var start = $scope.itemsPerPage * ($scope.currentPage - 1);
    var limit = $scope.itemsPerPage;
    service.getRandomsItems(criteria, start, limit).then(
        function(result) {
            var remainder = $scope.totalItems % $scope.itemsPerPage
            if (remainder > 0)
                $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage) + 1;
            else
                $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage);

            ctrl.displayed = result.randomsItems;
            $scope.totalItems = result.total;
            ctrl.isLoading = false;
        });
    };
}
```

and I call this function in my controller too to handle the paging issue

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {
    $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
    ctrl.callServer($scope.criteria);
}
```

As you can see, my function callServer returns ctrl.displayed which is the rows that displayed in current page

Now I want to work with new page so I called  ctrl.callServer to get new page then I called ctrl.selectCurrentPage() just like that

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {
    $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
    ctrl.callServer($scope.criteria);
    ctrl.selectCurrentPage() // I want this function to be called when ctrl.callServer($scope.criteria) is finished
}
```

where

```
ctrl.selectCurrentPage = function() {
    ctrl.selection.push(this.displayed[i].userId);
    ctrl.selectionRow.push(this.displayed[i]);
}
```

in Simple English I want ctrl.selectCurrentPage to be called when ctrl.callServer is finsih and get the new data
but that not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a **promise** from `callServer` and use it in `pageChanged`.

The first step:

```
this.callServer = function callServer(criteria) {
    ctrl.searchParameters = criteria;
    ctrl.isLoading = true;
    var start = $scope.itemsPerPage * ($scope.currentPage - 1);
    var limit = $scope.itemsPerPage;

    return service.getRandomsItems(criteria, start, limit).then(function(result) {
        var remainder = $scope.totalItems % $scope.itemsPerPage
        if (remainder > 0)
            $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage) + 1;
        else
            $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage);

        ctrl.displayed = result.randomsItems;
        $scope.totalItems = result.total;
        ctrl.isLoading = false;
    });
};
```

Then:

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {
    $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
    ctrl.callServer($scope.criteria).then(function () {
        ctrl.selectCurrentPage();
    });
}
```

Try to avoid callback hell. Please read [the article](http://blog.xebia.com/promises-and-design-patterns-in-angularjs/) for some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

pass it as a callback;

```
this.callServer = function callServer(criteria, callback) {
                            ctrl.searchParameters = criteria;
                            ctrl.isLoading = true;
                            var start = $scope.itemsPerPage * ($scope.currentPage - 1);
                            var limit = $scope.itemsPerPage;
                            service.getRandomsItems(criteria, start, limit).then(
                                            function(result) {
                                                var remainder = $scope.totalItems % $scope.itemsPerPage
                                                if (remainder > 0)
                                                    $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage) + 1;
                                                else
                                                    $scope.numPages = parseInt($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage);
                                                ctrl.displayed = result.randomsItems;
                                                $scope.totalItems = result.total;
                                                ctrl.isLoading = false;
                                                callback();
                                            });
                        };

                    } ]);



$scope.pageChanged = function(currentPage) {

                    $scope.currentPage = currentPage;
                    ctrl.callServer($scope.criteria, ctrl.selectCurrentPage);
                }
```